# Haskell - A specific type error with my own data type

Tags: haskell, types, typeerror

I am trying to write an interpreter for Brainf*ck in Haskell. But I am getting a type error.

Only the relevant parts of the code is shown below:

```
--my own defined data type
data BFState = BFState {
  program :: String,      -- program being interpreted
  input :: String,  -- input for the program
  memory :: [Word8],     -- memory is a list of 8bit representation of INTs since only least 8 bits are read
  prog_pointer :: Int,         -- current pointer in the program STRING (pc)
  mem_pointer :: Int         -- current pointer in the memory LIST (pos)
}

--Initialise the BFState before the Intepreter runs the inputted BF code.
initState :: String -> String -> Int -> BFState
initState program input memSize = BFState program input (take memSize (repeat 0)) 0 0

--Helper function for the main function (bf program input)
run state = if isEnd state
            then return () --when reached the end, just return
            else do newState <- (iterateBF state) --update to new state after iterating one BF comand
                    run newState --run with new state

--the main function
bf program input = run (initState program input 10000)
```

Now, I get a type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `String'
            with actual type `BFState -> String'
In the first argument of `initState', namely `program'
In the first argument of `run', namely
  `(initState program input 10000)'
In the expression: run (initState program input 10000)
```

What is the compiler referring to when it says `actual type 'BFState -> String'` ?

----For sepp2k

```
iterateBF :: BFState -> IO BFState
iterateBF state = case (program state !! prog_pointer state) of
    '+' -> return state {memory = setMem state ((getMem state) + 1), prog_pointer = nextPP state}
    '-' -> return state {memory = setMem state ((getMem state) - 1), prog_pointer = nextPP state}
    '>' -> return state {mem_pointer = (mem_pointer state) + 1, prog_pointer = nextPP state}
    '<' -> return state {mem_pointer = (mem_pointer state) - 1, prog_pointer = nextPP state}
    '[' -> return state {prog_pointer = prog_pointer'} where
            prog_pointer' = findClosingBrace (program state) (prog_pointer state)
    ']' -> return state {prog_pointer = prog_pointer'} where
            prog_pointer' = findOpeningBrace (program state) (prog_pointer state)
    ',' -> let inputVal = fromIntegral (fromEnum (head (input state))) in 
           return state {memory = setMem state inputVal, prog_pointer = nextPP state, input = drop 1 (input state)}
    '.' -> do hPutChar stdout (chr (fromEnum $ getMem state))
              hFlush stdout
              return state { prog_pointer = prog_pointer state}
    otherwise -> return (state {prog_pointer = nextPP state}) --ignore other characters

--check if we are at the end of the program
isEnd :: BFState -> Bool
isEnd state = (prog_pointer state) >= length (program state)
```

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how the code you've posted can generate the error message you've shown. Are you sure you posted the code unchanged and that the line it's complaining about is the definition of `bf` (i.e. there isn't another line where you also have the expression `run (initState ...)`)? Does `bf` maybe have a type signature in your real code?

Comment: What happens if you use a different variable name than `program` in your definition of `bf`? At the moment you're trying to shadow the `program` defined in the BFState data definition, which does indeed have type `BFState -> String`

Comment: @Zopa That shouldn't be a problem though. Shadowing global bindings is perfectly legal in Haskell and should certainly not result in the local binding simply being ignored.

Comment: @sepp2k I only posted parts of the code that I thought were relevant to the error. For instance, the defination for `iterateBF` is not there. I am sure the code posted is unchanged. `bf` does not have a type signature in my real code. I am pretty new to haskell just as background.

Comment: @Zopa OMG ZOPA!!! I changed `program` to `prog and theres no compilation errors!

Comment: @ali And I am sure you're wrong. The more I think about it, the more convinced I am that the code you've posted can not possibly produce that error message.

Comment: @sepp2k uhh..okay, shall I like copy and paste again the code to the bottom of the question?

Comment: Yes, please. FYI: After filling in the missing definitions with, the code you've posted [compiles perfectly fine](http://codepad.org/h9fD2YIF).

Comment: @sepp2k Maybe he had a typo? say, `bf prgram input = run (initState program input 1000)`. That'd give the reported error message, no?

Comment: @Zopa Yes, it would. That's why I asked whether he was sure that he posted the code unchanged.

Comment: @Zopa i didnt have a typo and am pretty sure about it.

Comment: There's strong circumstantial evidence the other way :) It's the only thing I can think of that would lead to that error. Shadowing is perfectly legal --- it's just often a bad idea, because it can confuse you when things go wrong. Anyhow, glad your code compiles now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the type of "program" (the first argument to your initState function) isn't String. It's actually BFState -> String, which you can verify by typing in ":t program" in the ghci prompt (without the quotes, of course).

Comment: Again: With the definition of `bf` as shown in the question, the inferred type of `program` (the first parameter of `bf`) should be `String`, not `BFState -> String`.

Comment: @Ali seems to make sense. changing `program` to something else causes no compilation errors. could it be that `program` defined in the `data BFState` is like globally accessible. That is to say any occurance of `program` in the following definations will be referring to that?

Comment: @ali No. I mean, yes, it *is* globally accessible, but local bindings always shadow global bindings. Inside the definition of `bf` the identifier `program` should always refer to the local `program` (i.e. `bf`'s first parameter) - never the global `program`. The only way this wouldn't be so would if you had typoed the parameter name in your real code (so it actually reads something like `bf programm input = run (initState program input 10000)`).

Comment: @sepp2k Ahhh i see where you are coming from. hmm.. no wonder dave4420 is mystified, as so are we.

Answer (score 1):

`program` is *expected* to have type `String` (because that's what the type signature of `initState` says it should be), but *actually* has type `BFState -> String` because that's the type of the first argument to `bf`.

If you supply an explicit type signature for `bf`, you will probably find that the actual mistake in your code is that somewhere you are calling `bf` with a first argument of type `BFState -> String`.

Comment: Since there is no type signature for `bf`, wouldn't the inferred type of `program` be `String` and the error would happen on the line where `bf` is called with anything other than a string as the first argument?

Comment: @dave4420 `bf` is not called anywhere else, and is only defined there in that last line.

Comment: @ali In that case I am mystified.